# How to set up a relative path to a portable JDK in IntelliJ IDEA portable?

Tags: intellij-idea

Since I code on several computers, I decided to install IntelliJ IDEA portable on my USB drive right next to my portable JDK installation. Now I would like to point to that JDK with a relative path inside IntelliJ so the IDE can find it everywhere. Unfortunately, it seems like I can only store the absolute path to the JDK, although the drive letter of my USB may change from device to device. Is there any way around this?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I tried but it doesn't seem like this variable can be used for the SDK path (in both creating a new project AND reconfiguring an existing project)

Answer (score 1):

JDK paths are stored in the IDE settings vs the project settings and currently there is no way to specify the JDK path relatively, it will always use the absolute path.

Please [vote for this feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-204577) if you need this feature in the future IntelliJ IDEA updates.